# Как взять словарь в кавычки в python?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

Я записываю словарь в базу данных mysql, но поскольку строку записать в столбец нельзя, я беру словарь в кавычки, а уже после, когда беру эту строку из бд я убираю кавычки с помощью `ast.literal_eval` и получаю словарь. Это работает как json. Если я сам напишу к примеру `"{'test': 123}"` и запишу в бд, это сработает. Но если у меня есть готовый словарь, значение которого уже есть и хранится в переменной, записать я его не могу. Я пытался делать `str(dict_name)` но появляется mysql syntax error.
Как преобразовать словарь в строку, чтобы был как бы словарь, но с кавычками, и считался строкой? Ведь я не могу записать словарь в бд.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4342219/7485582 Попробуйте `json.dumps` и `json.loads`

Comment: @КириллМалышев оформите ответ на русском?

Comment: @eri, я не уверен, что автору это поможет. Возможно, он как-то неправильно подставляет данные в запрос.

Answer (score 0):

Всё должно работать:

```
d = {'test': 123}
s = str(d)

print(d)       # {'test': 123}
print(type(d)) # <class 'dict'>
print(s)       # {'test': 123}
print(type(s)) # <class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Все, что нужно - добавить кавычки. Хотя бы даже и так:

```
d = {'test': 123}
s = '"' + str(d) + '"'
```